Что сделать, чтобы серверные действия, вызываемые из клиентского и серверного компонента работали с одними и теми же данными в next js
Ситуация такая, я хочу иметь на стороне сервера объект с множеством соединений баз данных под разными пользователями бд. Сделать я это пытаюсь просто через глобальную переменную Map<string, Sequelize> pool в файле pool.ts. Далее через функцию
'use server'
import {pool} from '/pool.ts'
import {getSequelize} from './sequelize.ts'

export async function AddSeq(username: string, password: string) {
    pool.set('username', await getSequelize(username, password));
}

Далее у меня есть функция для аутентификации, вызываемая из клиентского компонента. Она срабатывает из формы. Она работает, это проверенно.
Далее я пытался из серверного компонента получить доступ к переменной pool, а она пустая.
Как это фиксить?

Приведите код файла pool.ts. И еще у вас в set username это строка, а не переменная
